# HTML Img tag reload with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to load a image with Combo selection change:

Normally i can load a image in follow way:

Razor View :

```
<img id="imgPhotoIcon" src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Contractor", new { id = Model.ContactPersonnelID })" alt="Photo" style="width:150px; height:150px" />
```

Controller Part :

```
public Image GetPhoto(int id)
        {
            ContactPersonnel oContactPersonnel = new ContactPersonnel();
            oContactPersonnel = oContactPersonnel.GetWithImage(id, (Guid)Session[SessionInfo.wcfSessionID]);
            if (oContactPersonnel.Photo != null)
            {
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(oContactPersonnel.Photo);
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(m);
                img.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return img;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Now i want to load image with combo selection change based on selected item 
any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic problem here I think is you need to give url of image as a source of image so you need to return image url using json .Following is ajax method which would be called onchange of your combobox.Id is the input you want to pass to method.Or you can return base64string of byte array to ajax success

```
$.ajax({
                            cache:true,
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "@(Url.Action("GetPhoto", "Contractor"))",
                            data: "id=" + id,
                            success: function (data) {

  $('#imgPhotoIcon').attr('src', "data:image/jpg;base64," + data);

                                                   }
        });
```

Following is controller action

```
public Actionresult GetPhoto(int id)
        {
       //logic to get picture url goes here 
       // string picture=GetPictureUrl(id);

      byte[] imageByteArray = images;//Return byte array here
return Json(new { base64imgage =  Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteArray) }
                , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Hope It helps

Comment: Thanks  @Nitin varpe I have not any physical Image URL. Image get from SQL Server as a byte array. Please Consider this issue & suggest me

Comment: Answer updated please check. You can directly return byte array to ajax success

Comment: i try to return {byte[106561]} but my ajax success data hold something like : System.Byte[]

Comment: try with alert(data); whats it returning

Comment: alert message display : System.Byte[]

Comment: Check updated answer return converted Base64String using Jsonresult

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38960/discussion-between-nitin-varpe-and-csefaruk)